# Add value in specific index array

Tags: php, arrays

i have array data like this.

```
[0] => Array (
    [id] => 1
    [id_requestor] => 1
    [jam_input] => 2015-06-20 06:00:00
    [jam_pakai] => 2015-06-28 08:00:00
    [total_poin] => 30
    )
[1] => Array (
    [id] => 2
    [id_requestor] => 2
    [jam_input] => 2015-06-20 07:00:00
    [jam_pakai] => 2015-06-28 08:00:00
    [total_poin] => 10
    )
[2] => Array (
    [id] => 3
    [id_requestor] => 3
    [jam_input] => 2015-06-20 06:30:00
    [jam_pakai] => 2015-06-28 08:00:00
    [total_poin] => 5
    )
```

In above data, there is `total_poin`. This `total_poin` that i use later.
I want to sort `total_poin` array descending.
But i wont to use php built in array function.
Cause i have to use method from research paper like this.

```
for i=0 to i<main queue.size
   if jobi+1 length > jobi length then
    add jobi+1 in front of job i in the queue
end if
   if main queue.size = 0 then
    add job i last in the main queue
end if
```

And here is my implementation :

```
function LJFAlgorithm($time_str) {
        $batchData = getBatch($time_str);

        $ljf = [];
        for ($i=0; $i < count($batchData)-1; $i++) { 
            echo $batchData[$i+1]['total_poin'] ." >= ". $batchData[$i]['total_poin'] . " = " . ($batchData[$i+1]['total_poin'] >= $batchData[$i]['total_poin']);

            if ($batchData[$i+1]['total_poin'] >= $batchData[$i]['total_poin']) {
                echo ", Add " . $batchData[$i+1]['total_poin'] . " in front of " . $batchData[$i]['total_poin'];
            } else {
                echo ", Add " . $batchData[$i]['total_poin'] . " in front of " . $batchData[$i+1]['total_poin'];
            }

            echo '<br/>';
        }

        print_r($ljf);
    }
```

But it not work perfectly, i get one data missing.
Here is my output code :

```
10 >= 30 = , Add 30 in front of 10
5 >= 10 = , Add 10 in front of 5
```

`5` value not added in array.
How to fix that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you dont need to write `-1` here - `for ($i=0; $i < count($batchData)-1; $i++)`

Comment: What's your expected final output? This loop: `$i=0; $i < count($batchData)-1; $i++)` of course iterates exactly twice, because $i < 3-1 or $i < 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for ($i=0; $i <= count($batchData)-1; $i++)
```

Comment: or `for ($i=0; $i < count($batchData); $i++)` :P

Comment: But i get this error : `Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/carreq/functions.php on line 74`

Comment: The problem is when you merch 2 rows into 1, so you must still add to array one row.

Comment: @Daniel Change `if` statement  to??

Comment: I wrote it wrong. I thought when you should also control if a row is last in array, and add this 'if' before your 'if', with a different echo value and then end your loop. I hope when you understand what i thing.